# How to create audio and video calling in ionic framework using phonertc?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, phonertc

I want to create audio and video calling in ionic. 
How to run the demo file in phonertc ?
what are the steps that must be followed to test the phonertc demo file.
The folder structures are different in phonertc demo file compared to ionic project .
An INSTALL or README file in the client demo folder or a tutorial on the website on how to build and configure the demo app would be a plus.

Comment: How about you try something and let us know what you have tried ? + here is plugin : https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc

Comment: I have downloaded the demo file.but i am unable to run it using ionic framework